# Cannot stop function in Python

Tags: python, function

I am having problem with function that I have created, it does not stop, can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong?

```
import random

words = ["monitor", "mouse", "CPU", "keyboard"]

attempts = []

randomWord = random.choice(words)

noChar = len(randomWord)

print randomWord , noChar
print "Hello, Welcome to the game of Hangman. You have to guess the given word. The first word has", noChar, " letters."

def game():    
    guess = raw_input ("Please choose letter")
    attempts.append(guess)
    print (attempts)

    if guess in randomWord: 
        print "You have guessed the letter" 
    else: 
        print "Please try again"
    return()  

chance = raw_input ("Have a guess")

while chance!= randomWord:
    game()
```

Comment: When do you want it to stop?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  I'm not sure about 3.x, but I know in 2.x ```return``` is a statement (should not have parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

The input where you ask for a guess needs to be triggered more than once either inside the `game` function or every time it finishes.

You are only asking for `chance` at the beginning of the game. Unless the player immediately guesses the word it won't trigger the victory condition.

Something like this will fix it:

```
def game():    
    guess = input ("Please choose letter")
    attempts.append(guess)
    print (attempts)

    if guess in randomWord: 
        print ("You have guessed the letter" )
    else: 
        print ("Please try again")


while True:
    game()
    chance = input ("Have a guess")
    if chance == randomWord:
        print('You win!')
        break
```

Bonus tip: To print all the succesful guesses in order, meaning in the order they are in in the hidden word you can do something like:

```
def game():    
    guess = input ("Please choose letter")
    if guess in randomWord:
        success.append(guess)
    attempts.append(guess)
    print (attempts)
    print(sorted(success, key=randomWord.index))
    if guess in randomWord: 
        print ("You have guessed the letter" )
    else: 
        print ("Please try again")
```

Would output:

```
Hello, Welcome to the game of Hangman. You have to guess the given word. The first word has 7  letters.
Please choose letterm
[]
['m']
You have guessed the letter
Have a guesst
Please choose lettert
[]
['m', 't']
You have guessed the letter
Have a guess
Please choose lettero
[]
['m', 'o', 't']
You have guessed the letter
Have a guess
```

This allows the player to see what order the correct letters go in.